# Rotate base 64 image and insert into MySql as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, base64, image-rotation

I am just trying to rotate the image coming from the DB, which is base 64 format. and update back the rotated image into mysql.

My Image

```
$imageData=mysql_real_escape_string($rs[0]['image_data']);// base 64 format
$degrees = 180;
```

rotate image function

```
    ob_start();
    $destImage = imagerotate($imageData, $degrees, 0) ;     
    imageJPEG($destImage);
    $image_thumb =mysql_real_escape_string(ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
```

The control is not going inside ob_start(). Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to escape the data you read from the DB, you only escape it when you write it.
 The raw data isn't an image resource:

```
$imageData = $rs[0]['image_data'];
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$degrees = 180;

ob_start();
$destImage = imagerotate($im, $degrees, 0) ;     
imageJPEG($destImage);
$image_thumb =mysql_real_escape_string(ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

The other thing you might need to add is decode/encode for base64. Easier to store as a blob that way. otherwise you are escaping a binary string which could be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is completely working fine.. But i have one issue.. For the first time when i rotate image , for suppose i'l give $degrees = 90; . its giving me 270 degree rotation. and for the next time its working perfect.

Comment: some image types are stored upside down. Perhaps if the original image is upside down that property isn't preserved. Are they all JPEG to start?

Comment: Yes they are all JPEG. But why first time rotation acting wierd.. for 0, it wont affect. if i select 90, its becoming 270. if i select 180, no orientation wil occur, but half image will appear

Comment: There must be some corruption in the image data.